# Spring Boot + SpringSecurity + OAuth2 client - use custom UserDetailsService or AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am creating website using Spring Boot, Spring MVC and spring-security-oauth2 and I am trying to authenticate my locally stored users against Google, Facebook, GitHub ... OAuth2 services. I also have standard username-password for them.

My idea is to store pair of [OAuth2_provider_type,OAuth2_subjectId] for each user to local database from the first success oauth login and then use this pair to find correct user when user authenticate himself by Google (or FB...) again. I have correctly authenticate with Google/Facebook but I don't know how to connect my local stored users to Spring OAuth2 Security and get them to SecurityContext.

Could somebody point me to some example or integration test where I can see something similar?

I am scanning spring-security-oauth2 sourcecode and I am confused little bit - do I need OAuth2 AuthorizationServer or ResourceServer for that?

Thanks for any help!